# Project templates for Windows Forms App (.NET Core) are not showing up in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

As title and following screenshots shown, I have tried both `Repair` and `re-install` Visual Studio 2019, but something is wrong in my environment.

I am looking for the template: `Windows Forms App (.NET Core)`.

Can anybody help? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using .net core 5.0? - most of the templates have been slightly renamed so now they are not using the word "core" with 5.0. I remember seeing something to this effect in one of the videos from MS.

Answer (score 2):

**In last visual studio update** (I use vs 2019 version 16.10.3)

1. Select [Windows Forms App] (Not specified with any Target-Framework
   version)
   [image: 1]
2. After select Project Name and Location and ..., click [Next] button
   [image: 2]
3. In next page opened you can select [Target Framework] (.Net core or
   .Net 5)
   [image: 3]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @DavidB mentioned, templates are renamed.

After 2 times of Uninstall-Restart-Install, I am able to create `Windows Forms App(.NET)`, and its version is `.NET Core 3.1` and I am able to change its version to `.NET 5.0`.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: VS2019 buggy. This is what happened to me, template for .net winform not available..